# If a basis is also a subbasis for the same topology, is it closed under finite intersections?

Tags: general-topology

I'm trying to understand a little bit the relation between a basis and a subbasis for a given topology. So suppose $S$ is a subbasis for a topology, say, $\delta_s$. Suppose that $S$ is also closed under finite intersections. Then it follows that $S$ is also a basis for $\delta_s$. Does the converse also holds? I.e., suppose that $S$ is a subbasis for $\delta_s$. Now suppose that $S$ is also a basis for $\delta_s$. Does it follow that $S$ is closed under finite intersections? I've tried to prove this assertion, but to no avail, so I'm starting to think it's probably not true; however, I also don't know how to produce a counterexample.

Comment: Every basis of a topology is a subbasis of that topology, and there are bases which are not closed under intersections (balls in euclidean space, say)

Comment: Yes, obviously, I don't know what I was thinking!